# how to run two threads of same class using one object using QThread in cpp?

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

i had a class whose member functions are VideoCapture and VideoWrite.
i want to run two threads to do the two process parallely.
I had observed that we need to create a class object everytime to run a different thread. 
Is there any way not to create everytime a different class object?

Answer (score 2):

You can't really run a class in two different threads - generally you move a class instance into a thread. You are probably better of making two separate classes, a reader/capture class and a writer class and put each in their own thread... this is quite simple and effective.

An alternative if you really want to keep the class together you could use QtConcurrent to achieve this - depending on how your class works. You could run your capture / write functions (or any heavy-on-processor functions) in qtconcurrent to farm off the heavy lifting - while event-handling/event-loop can just be done in the main thread (or even a separate thread to move this completely away from the main thread). See:

[run member function qith QtConcurrent](https://wiki.qt.io/QtConcurrent-run-member-function)

and

[QtConcurrent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qtconcurrent.html)